# How to compress subpixel text bitmap

Tags: compression, jpeg, lossless, subpixel, lossy-compression

Recently, I am doing jobs about Windows clearType text compression; Windows text font use sub-pixel rendering tech which making the text font edge full of mess colors, like below.

[image]

I have try the jpeg, zstd, lz4, the compression ratio of them cannot satisfied me ,SO anyone have experience or ideas to compress this type of bitmap, lossy or lossless?

Comment: Please show what commands or code you have tried and what errors are you encountering.

Comment: PNG lossless should do a decent job due to the font's vertical and horizontal symmetry. You can probably compress it as an 8-bit palette image since there aren't that many unique colors.